# "Trusted zone" in ESET Smart Security still works even with "ESET Service" stopped?

Tags: networking, security, remote-desktop, nod32, eset

I have ESET Smart Security installed on computer `A`, and I usually connect from PC `B` to `A` using RDP. I have to add the IP of `B` to "trusted zone" on `A` so that `B` is not blocked, [like in this tutorial](http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN2351).

Recently I was trying to connect from `C` to `A` using RDP, and I stopped the "ESET Service" instead of adding the IP of `C` to trusted zone of `A`, but `C` is still blocked until I started ESET again and added the IP of `C` to trusted zone again.

I'm rather curious that, is *adding some IP to "trusted zone" in ESS* changes some configuration of Windows permanently? Why connection from `C` is still blocked even with "ESET Service" stopped?

Answer (score 1):

ESS uses kernel drivers (`epfw.sys`, `epfwwfp.sys`, `epfwlwf.sys`) for network traffic filtering. These drivers have loaded firewall settings in kernel-mode, so there is no need for transition to user-mode just to evaluate every single network packet.

This is why network rules are applied even if `ESET Service` is not running.

Comment: Thx! So is there a way to break the rules automatically when `ESET Service` is down ?

Comment: Don't think so. But why do you need to stop service? If you want to temporarily disable firewall just use `Pause firewall` option from ESS tray menu.